# How can I get the "Visual Studio 2012" cmake generator on mac?

Tags: c++, cmake

For a CS class I'm taking, the C++ assignments need to be submitted as Visual Studio 2012 projects. I'd really rather not use Visual Studio, so I'm thinking about creating cmake projects instead, then generating Visual Studio project files using cmake. I know this is possible using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 11"`, but this only seems to work on Windows. When I run cmake on my computer, I get a list of generators, and the Visual Studio generators aren't listed. I know that [the cmake website](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) says that generators are platform specific, but is there some way to get these generators working on OS X?

**Edit**: For anyone coming across this question later, you should look into premake instead of messing with cmake. If you get premake 5, which is currently the development version, you can use it to generate Visual Studio 2012 files from Mac or Linux without needing to use Windows at all (on Windows you can generate Xcode projects without having to use OS X as well).

Comment: Remember that CMake based projects still have CMake dependency that is not easy to remove.

Comment: @drescherjm I was not aware of that. Could you elaborate? Does the professor need to have cmake installed or do anything different?

Comment: CMake will generate Visual Studio projects that contain targets that externally execute CMake as build step to regenerate the Visual Studio project as well as CTest ... For simple examples you may be able to remove these targets that depend on CMake. Although I have no experience in doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake needs to call Visual Studio compiler to check compiler version, so I doub't it could find it on OS X, that why it's platform specific.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. Do you know if I can use a vm to generate the Visual Studio project files, then send it to my professor who does not have cmake installed, or does he need to have cmake installed on his computer to build the project?

Comment: Once you've generated the Visual Studio project files, you can send them, they will be loaded by any Visual Studio, no need to have cmake installed.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Gerald as far as i know, cmake-generated projects capture all sort of absolute paths, it will break if you move it to another folder. Copying it to another machine will almost certainly break it as well.

Comment: Hmmm, it depends on how cmake are made. But library paths and include paths can be relative, so as output paths. But probably copying projects files on same path on another computer has better chance to work.